# How to deal with async. findOrCreate method for passport and mongoose

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, mongoose, passport.js

Authentication module 'Passport' requires a FindOrCreate method in order to do a login. I am using mongoose in order to save my users with the following schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    accounts: []
});
```

The accounts array holds objects that represent facebook accounts, like `{provider: "facebook", uid: "someFacebookId"}`.

My authentication strategy looks like this:

```
// Authentication Strategy
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: CONFIG.fb.appId,
    clientSecret: CONFIG.fb.appSecret,
    callbackURL: CONFIG.fb.callbackURL
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {

      User.find({ 'accounts.uid': profile.id, 'accounts.provider': 'facebook' }, function(err, olduser) {

          if(olduser._id) {
            console.log('User: ' + olduser.firstname + ' ' + olduser.lastname + ' found and logged in!');
            done(null, olduser);
          } else {
            var newuser = new User();
            var account = {provider: "facebook", uid: profile.id};
            newuser.accounts.push(account);
            newuser.firstname = profile.name.givenName;
            newuser.lastname = profile.name.familyName;
            newuser.email = "TBD...";

            newuser.save(function(err) {
              if(err) { throw err; }
              console.log('New user: ' + newuser.firstname + ' ' + newuser.lastname + ' created and logged in!');
              done(null, newuser);
            });
          }
        });
    });
  }
));
```

**Problem:** After querying my database (`User.find(...)`) the callback function is executed immediately without waiting for my database to answer. This results in a undefined `olduser` object. So I am getting a dublicate of the same user into my database every time this user tries to login.

How do I handle this asynchronous callback properly?

Comment: I know this isn't directly related to the question, but isn't that find query a little dangerous? It looks for a user with any accounts.uid of the given value and with any accounts.provider of 'facebook'. But what forces them to be the same accounts list element? That is, what if another user had a matching uid with a different provider?

Comment: I am assuming it is looking fo the combination of both values, which should be unique.

Comment: This assuming is danger. Because find in array of accounts matched if the user has a facebook account and *ANY* account has that uid. If somebody has a OpenAuth server, then he can login as any user by return the uid he wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User.find` returns an *array* of documents that match your conditions.  In your case you want to use `User.findOne` instead, and then check `if (olduser)...` to determine if a matching doc was found.

Comment: Thank you. That took me a while now. Thank you :-)

Comment: Heads up, before you go into production, you'll want to have a look into transactions: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/two-phase+commit

Otherwise, two users signing up at the same time with the same username will break the system.  Obviously not too much of a problem *just* for facebook, since usernames are already unique, but it will play more of a role as you augment your authentication system with other strategies.

Answer (score 3):

Hate to nitpick, but the other methods mentioned here break if two users try to signup at the same time-- before you go into production, you'll want to have a look into transactions: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/two-phase+commit

Answer (score 1):

```
process.nextTick(function () {
      var query = User.findOne({ 'fbId': profile.id });
      query.exec(function (err, oldUser) {
        console.log(oldUser);
        if(oldUser) {
          console.log('User: ' + oldUser.name + ' found and logged in!');
          done(null, oldUser);
        } else {
          var newUser = new User();
          newUser.fbId = profile.id;
          newUser.name = profile.displayName;
          newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;

          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if(err) {throw err;}
            console.log('New user: ' + newUser.name + ' created and logged in!');
            done(null, newUser);
          }); 
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: first we query our database if there is a oldUser, if there is a oldUser we call done and if there is no user in the database we create a new user and save it to our database.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for that: [mongoose-findorcreate](https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate)